# PHP code to fetch data from mysql server for mobile app

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

My PHP code to fetch data from mysql server to display which works perfect for website but i want to use the same for making mobile app,
Will it work or not for mobile app?. becuse i am using below ajax call (below code).

also how i can use json here, as i am newbe need help.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$filmId=$_GET['filmId'];
$sql ="SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(filmReleaseDate, '%d %b %Y' ) filmReleaseDate FROM films where filmId ='$filmId'";
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id=$row['filmId'];
    $name=$row['filmName'];
  $year=$row['filmYear'];

echo "$name, $year";

}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is ajax code, when i click on href it will process above php request to fetch data.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "./searchfilmsbyname.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "";
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<li><a href ='filmdetails.php?filmId=" + arr[i].Id + "'>" + arr[i].Film + "</a></li>";
        if ((i + 1) == arr.length) {
            document.getElementById("searchfilmsbyname").innerHTML = out;
            $("#searchfilmsbyname").listview('refresh');
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: As a fair warning, your query can be SQL injected because you're using a variable from user input directly in your query. I would strongly recommend reading on [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I don't know if it's ok for me to suggest a piece of kit I wrote, but have a look at [Aye Aye Api](https://github.com/AyeAyeApi/Api). It's still in beta and lacking proper documentation (there is a quick start guide) or even a [website](http://ayeayeapi.com/) but it's designed especially to make building API's as easy as possible. Mix it with [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) and you'll have pretty robust API MySQL access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how it is working on your web-site, perhaps you are including it instead of using ajax, but the problem with the code above is that you are not sending back valid json so:

```
function myFunction(response) {
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  ...
```

will fail because:

```
$id=$row['filmId'];
$name=$row['filmName'];
$year=$row['filmYear'];

// this does not generate valid json:
echo "$name, $year";
```

What you should do, is add all rows to an array and only at the end output only that array encoded as json:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rows[] = array('id' => $row['filmId'],
                    'name' => $row['filmName'],
                    'year' => $row['filmYear']);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Apart from that you have an sql injection problem. You should use a prepared statement instead of injecting your variable directly into your query.

Comment: @ jeroen if i use your code i am gettting data like :[{"id":"55","name":"Godzilla","year":"2014"}] i want something like "Godzilla, 2014" i am able to get json data but how i can convert them to see the same to user?

Comment: @RRPandey Yes, but that is what your javascript is expecting and what you need if you want to do things like `... + arr[i].id + ...` in javascript. You must choose whether your php script returns normal text or json, you can't have it both ways unless you start testing for an ajax call or a regular include and modify the output accordingly.

Comment: since i am going to use that for mobile app, i want to use that json format in form of text like "Godzilla, 2014" how i can use the same as i am very new in js so its bit getting tough

Comment: @RRPandey You can't, not reliably at least, json is the way to go when javascript is involved. You could send an extra value with your ajax request to indicate the output should be json and use that in your script to detemine the kind of output.

Comment: ok, in that case kindly let me know if i use above php code on href such as <a href ='filmdetails.php?filmId=" + arr[i].Id + "'>" will it work on mobile app?

Comment: @RRPandey I'm not exactly sure what you mean, why is there a difference between the web-site and the mobile app? The only difference is screen size so the same thing could easily work on both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75405/discussion-between-rrpandey-and-jeroen).